# Can privately administered colleges and universities in the USA successfully run without government funding?

Tags: united-states, funding, united-kingdom

Can privately administered colleges and universities in the USA and the UK successfully run without government (either state or federal) funding?

By "government funding," I mean any kind of money coming from a US state or the federal government that hinders the institution from implementing its own set of rules.

**Related:**

1. https://law.stackexchange.com/q/101381/32068
2. https://law.stackexchange.com/q/101491/32068

Comment: Just the first site on Google: https://usafacts.org/articles/what-do-universities-do-with-the-billions-they-receive-from-the-government/ - in 2018 about $100B was for student aid (scholarship, work-study, loans), then grants (NSF, NIH, etc.), and a bit for contracts (I have contracts with universities from my national lab group).

Comment: Short answer is yes for the USA. I've provided a list as my answer. A great follow-up questions is _why?_...

Comment: Define funding. Many U.S. colleges, very famous ones among them, are private institutions. Many of them perform research for the government, like for any other entity (but could likely survive with only private research). Do you consider that federal funding? Many students receive [federal aid](https://studentaid.gov/); do you consider that federal funding? [Most (even private) colleges are tax-exempt](https://www.aau.edu/key-issues/tax-exempt-status-universities-and-colleges); do you consider that federal funding?

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica I took this to be _any_ federal funding. But, yes, it is unclear.

Comment: @RichardErickson For me, there is a huge difference between a private institution (of which there are very few in Germany) and one that is actually government-funded (and run) (the vast majority in Germany). The difference between accepting public or only private research grants is much lesser. And finally, I would not consider student aid "funding" at all, and the idea that a college would not accept students who receive government aid for fear of undue government interference seems extreme and ludicrous to me. What about food stamps? Public transportation? Streets?

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica, ah, you have a German perspective. I have a US perspective. Most "private" US schools fit your definition. However, there are some schools that do not want _ANY_ federal funding i nthe US. And yes, these people want to get rid of food stamps, public transportation (e.g., city busses, Amtrak), and at least decrease funding to street (some libertarians want all roads to be toll roads). In the US, there are some schools that forgot _any_ federal funding to avoid federal rules that happen to include anti-discrimination laws.

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica for example, https://www.cbpp.org/blog/house-republicans-snap-amendments-would-take-food-away-from-more-than-1-million-low-income https://www.wpr.org/transportation/republicans-vote-cut-public-transit-funding-milwaukee-madison and  https://www.lp.org/blogs-staff-lp-monday-message-toll-roads/

Comment: @user366312 thanks. that's what I thought you meant, but there was some confusion in the comments.

Comment: @user366312 It would be helpful if you would include that in the question ("any federal funding as defined in the Civil Rights Act of 1964". I am still unsure whether student aid is contingent on the institution complying with that law (after all, it's the student who is funded, not the college). I'm still not sure whether being tax exempt is contingent either. "Being tax exempt" as a non-profit scientific organization is not the same as "funding" in my book. (Let's assume the college is properly licensed as an educational institution.)

Comment: @user366312 I [asked a question over at law](https://law.stackexchange.com/q/101491/3312) about that.

Comment: @user366312 Funding from the state would not be "federal," so if that's what you mean, you should say that.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes.
There are some colleges/universities (in the US, I do not know about the UK) that do not accept federal fundings due to their belief and principles.
These institutions are the "counter-example" that proves the rule of why most institutions do accept federal fundings.

[Dean Clancy maintains a list](https://deanclancy.com/a-list-of-colleges-that-dont-take-federal-money/).
Here is his list as of March 2024:

- Aletheia Christian College (Idaho)
- Bethlehem College & Seminary (Minnesota)
- Boyce College (Kentucky)
- Christendom College (Virginia)
- Crown College (Tennessee)
- Faith Bible College (Maine)
- Grove City College (Pennsylvania)
- Gutenberg College (Oregon)
- Hildegard College (California)
- Hillsdale College (Michigan)
- Mid-America Baptist Theological Seminary (Tennessee)
- Mount Liberty College (Utah)
- New College Franklin (Tennessee)
- New Saint Andrews College (Idaho)
- Patrick Henry College (Virginia)
- Pensacola Christian College (Florida)
- Principia College (Illinois)
- Southern Baptist Theological Seminary (Kentucky)
- Southwestern Baptist Theological Seminary (Texas)
- Weimar University (California)
- Wyoming Catholic College (Wyoming)

If you browse this site, you can gain insight into the common belief system of these colleges.
They are mostly fiscal and religious [Christian] conservatives who do not want a large federal government nor federal influence on their education.

Comment: The list you provided includes just colleges (and seminaries) are there any universities, as in larger institutions that also have consistent research output, that do not accept federal funding?

Comment: @jDAQ My guess is not for the US. Almost all researcher in academics obtain (or at least try to) federal funding. Plus, there are private research foundations that do not accept federal funds. so, why have a non-federal research university? A college can teach and private research institutes can research. If you can find anything, I'd be happy to edit it in.

Comment: I'm most familiar with Hillsdale, where there is research output on the level of peer liberal arts colleges.  Faculty can receive funding from private foundations.  In some cases they gain an affiliation with an independent research corporation and receive federal funding through that entity.

Comment: @PaulT. thank you for that insight. Makes sense. Also, would be interesting thought experiment if the rest of higher ed operated that way.

Comment: One bit of context is that the main reason why these US colleges refuse federal funding (including federally backed student loans) is to avoid complying with [Title IX of the education amendments](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Title_IX) to the civil rights act, see e.g. [Grove City College v. Bell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grove_City_College_v._Bell) and the [Civil Rights Restoration Act](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Civil_Rights_Restoration_Act_of_1987) a.k.a. the Grove City Bill.

Comment: @PaulT. I agree with the context, it's just not part of the OP's question. I even suggest it as a new question in another comment. I was being diplomatic with my suggestion into looking as to why.

Answer (score 5):

The situation in the UK depends on your definitions of public funding and public/private universities.

In the UK all universities are non-governmental institutions (the most common corportate form is a schedule 3 charity, which replaced royal charter as the most common form recently).

However, most universities in the UK are publically funded, in that the government issues loans to students to pay for tuition, and only about 50% of students actaully end up paying these back. In addition, most universities recieve a small amount of teaching grant and a larger (although still relevitively small) quality related research block grant (a grant awarded on the average quality of the research, not for any particular project). The balance of funding usually comes from research grants, which again, mostly come from the government.

Universities that accept students funded by student loans must follow various government mandated rules and submit to regulation by the Office for Students.

There are a very small number of universities in the UK that don't accept government regulations, and therefore can't accept students funded by government loans. This is what is called "private" universities in the UK. There are 8 such institutions, and mostly they are small specialist institutions, such as "University of Law", only two are "general purpose" as far as I can tell: The university of Buckingham and Arden University, and even these specialise in vocation and professional degrees rather than the usual academic subjects.

Answer (score 0):

This seems a broad question as there are a great variety of institutions and programs. Some might, but many important ones could not.

Regardless, the status quo is that federal funding for research is extremely important (it has always been). Quoting from [an NSF source](https://ncses.nsf.gov/pubs/nsb202326):

> Institutions of higher education in the United States spent nearly $90 billion on R&D in FY 2021, the highest amount reported to date. Most of that spending (55%) was financed by federal government sources.

I don't think it is guesswork to state that simply doing away with this source of funding would thoroughly alter  the nature of education in the USA. Look only at what has happened to the social sciences and humanities as their funding has shrunk in favor of STEM. Most European universities also rely to a large degree on government funding  to sustain research.

Government funding is important (I would say essential) because research carried out in universities is to a large degree an educational experience, typically with no direct financial return but producing highly educated graduates.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.

Comment: "Can privately administered colleges and universities in the USA and the UK successfully run without federal funding?" @AzorAhai-him- Of course it answers this, it depends on your definition of "successful". According to my answer, the answer for many universities (private or not) is **no**, because research and associated educational activities would be severely compromised (truncated by 50+%, although admin would take some of the hit) and they represents an important part of the mission of many universities.

Comment: I agree the last paragraph might be superfluous. I merely tried to explain why Universities bother with research at all.

Answer (score -1):

In the US, very few colleges and universities, even public ones, receive direct Federal funding. Or, at least, no substantial contribution to cost of operation. Public universities in the US have support from individual states, not the federal government. Some colleges (community and junior colleges) have local governmental funding (city, county, ...).

There is indirect support, however. Students are funded through loans and some grants. But those loans and grants can be used at any accredited place, public or private. Research is partly funded through competitive grants from the Federal government, but those are also available to faculty at both public (state funded) and private institutions. Private organizations (IBM, Google, ...) also provide grants.

And, most research grants, while they go to individuals and groups of faculty, do provide funding to the institutions through "overhead" which consumes a fairly large piece of a grant. This is to support the general infrastructure of the university (buildings and such) as well as labs, computing infrastructure, and similar things. But the flow is technically Government -> individual -> institution, rather than Government -> institution -> individual. The institution also incurs costs in administering the grant so as to assure compliance with regulations and proper use of the monies.

The current administration (Biden et. al. 2024) is trying to forgive a lot of student loans. That money is Federal and benefits the individuals directly. It does, of course, represent funds previously paid to colleges and universities, both public and private.

Many universités, public and private, do work on behalf of government, both Federal and state, and that is funded.

Private institutions (and to an increasingly large extent public ones) are funded by student tuition and gifts of donors, often graduates of those institutions. Both my undergraduate and doctoral institutions are continuously (daily emails) begging me for contributions. Harvard University, for example, has a vast endowment that comes from past contributions over its long life and careful investment of the funds.

As for success, my old undergraduate place was then a small private liberal arts college with about 2000 students. It is now listed as an R2 and has been in operation for about 175 years without federal funding. It is successful in sending people into academic careers as well as business and the sciences.

The Federal government has a role in accreditation and in assuring fairness of treatment through regulations. The states also take such a role, as do private organizations.

See https://www2.ed.gov/about/overview/fed/role.html for the federal role in education in the US.

I suspect that the UK answer is quite different. And, I think that the US usage of "public institution" is different from that in the UK. Here it implies creation by a state government and some institutional control by a state, such as New York. Private institutions, OTOH, are created by private entities, sometimes church units, and funded mostly independent of government other than as mentioned above.

Comment: I disagree with your first sentence. See this article that would suggest they receive direct federal funding from a legal perspective: https://www.nationalaffairs.com/publications/detail/the-strange-evolution-of-title-ix

Comment: @RichardErickson, that article is about regulation, not funding.

Comment: Yes and the regulations apply to universities because they receive direct federal funding.

Comment: @RichardErickson, hmmm.. Actually they apply because we have regulations about lots of things without funding. It's the law, not a quid pro quo.

Comment: Generally, you are correct about laws and regulations applying to everyone, but in this case you are wrong. Title IX applies to universities that receive _any_ federal funding. No federal funding, no Title IX (and some other federal regulations). The linked article describes law was snuck in as a rider.

Comment: Also, you overall answer is correct but how universities are functionally funded (i.e., not from taxpayers at any level as the primary source of income), but **any** federal funding causes extra federal regulation.

Comment: I believe your chain of funding for research is wrong. Federal grants and contracts are always made to an organization which administers the funds for the proposed and approved research by an individual. If a researcher wants to go to another institution, they have to get approval to move the funds to that other institution. Approval is rarely withheld.

Comment: To my knowledge the only Federal colleges and universities are the Army, Air Force and Naval academies and the lesser known Coast Guard and Merchant Marine Academies. In addition, Gallaudet College (for deaf people) was founded by the Federal Government but I do not know if this is still a Federal institution. If there are others I would like to know.

Comment: @DavidSmith thanks for the input. For trivia sake, BIE directly operates two post-secondary institutions as well https://www.bia.gov/bie

Comment: There is also the Uniformed Services University of the health sciences in Washington, DC, operated by the Defense Department.